# Threads are slow c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

im trying to draw a mandelbrot and want to use 4 threats to do the calculation at the same time but a different part of the image , here are the functions

```
void Mandelbrot(int x_min,int x_max,int y_min,int y_max,Image &im)
{

    for (int i = y_min; i < y_max; i++)
    {

        for (int j = x_min; j < x_max; j++)
        {
            //scaled x and y cordinate
            double x0 = mape(j, 0, W, MinX, MaxX);
            double y0 = mape(i, 0, H, MinY, MaxY);

            double x = 0.0f;
            double y = 0.0f;
            int iteration = 0;

            double z = 0;
            while (abs(z)<2.0f && iteration < maxIteration)// && iteration < maxIteration)
            {

                double xtemp = x * x - y * y + x0;
                y = 2 * x * y + y0;
                x = xtemp;
                iteration++;

                z = x * x + y * y;

                if (z > 10)//must be 10
                    break;
            }

            int b =mape(iteration, 0, maxIteration, 0, 255);
            if (iteration == maxIteration)
                b = 0;

            im.setPixel(j, i, Color(b,b,0));
        }
    }
}
```

mape functions just convert a number from one range to another

Here is the thread function

```
void th(Image& im)
{
    float size = (float)im.getSize().x / num_th;
    int x_min = 0, x_max = size, y_min = 0, y_max = im.getSize().y;

    thread t[num_th];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_th; i++)
    {

        t[i] = thread(Mandelbrot, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, ref(im));
        x_min = x_max;
        x_max += size;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i<num_th; i++)
    {
        t[i].join();
    }

}
```

The main function looks like this

```
int main()
{
   Image img;
   while(1)//here is while window.open()
   {
     th(img);
     //here im drawing

   }
}
```

So i am not getting any performance boost but it gets even slower , can anyone tell my where is the problem what im doing wrong , it happened to me before too

I sow a question what is an image , it's a class from the SFML library dont'n know if this is of any help.

Comment: the loop inside `main` is endless!. does this program finish?!! This code won't compile or it's incomplete.

Comment: @assmo yes it does the condition for the loop is while the window is open loop and draw , but this is not the problem.

Comment: Make too many threads and you'll slow down the system as it fights over cores. Are you doing this? Smurfed if I know. You have simultaneous unsynchronized access to `im`. Whether this is a problem or not depends on the smarts built into `setPixel`. So is this a problem? Smurfed if I know.

Comment: There are a lot of details missing from the question.  What is `Image`?  How are you performing the timings?  Is the build optimized?  You are also using non-standard features such as variable length arrays.

Comment: @G.M. it's from the sfml library

Comment: All this starting of threads will slow everything down considerably. If you can use C++17 or newer, you can use the built-in thread pool. `std::for_each(std::execution::par, ...`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is incomplete to be able to answer you concretely, but there are a few suspicions:

1. Spawning a thread has non-trivial overhead.  If the amount of work performed by the thread is not large enough, the overhead of launching it may cost more than any gains you would get through parallelism.
2. Excessive locking and contention.  Does not look like a problem in your code, as you don't seem to use any locks at all.  Be careful (though as long as they don't write to the same addresses, it should be correct.)
3. False sharing: Possible problem in your code.  Cache lines tend to be 64 bytes.  Any write to any portion of a cache line causes the whole line to be committed to memory.  If two threads are looking at the same cache line and one of them writes to it, even if all the other threads use a different part of that cache line, they all will have their copy invalidated and will have to re-fetch.  This can cause significant problems if multiple threads work in non-overlapping data that share a cache line and cause these invalidations.  If they iterate at the same rate through the same data, it can cause this problem to recur over and over. This problem can be significant, and always worth considering.
4. memory layout causing your cache to be thrashed.  While walking through an array, going "across" may align with actual memory layout, reading one full cacheline after another, but scanning "vertically" touches one portion of a cache line then jumps to the corresponding portion of another cache line.  If this happens in many threads and you have a lot of memory to churn through, it can mean that your cache is vastly underutilized.  Just something to beware of, whether your machine is row- or column- major, and write code to match it, and avoid jumping around in memory.